# duplicate symbol error in C

Tags: c, duplicate-symbol

I have the following code layout

header.h

```
#ifndef _header_h
#define _header_h
void empty(float *array, int l)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1 ; i<=l ; i++)
    {
        array[i]=0;
    }

}

#endif
```

and two files (lets call them file1.c and file2.c)

```
#include "header.h"

void function/*1 or 2*/(){

     ....
     empty(a,b);
     ....
}
```

So compiling works fine but the linker command fails as the compiler says that there is a duplicate function definition. How can I avoid that with still using the header file? It is working fine when I only define the function in the header and create another .c file containing the full function. I always thought declaring it in the header is the way to go.

Comment: Don't know why people are downvoting you.

Answer (score 4):

> I always thought declaring it in the header is the way to go.

Yes, it is. **Declaring** it in the header is fine. It is not any good to **define** it in a header, though. (unless it's `static inline`, but you probably don't want to do that these days.)

Answer (score 3):

You should never have things in a header that require memory in the running program. This is a rough way of specifying it, but it works pretty well in practice.

In other words, the header should only have the *prototype* for the function, which is a compile-time thing that doesn't "exist" in the running program (unlike the code of the function itself, which of course exists at runtime):

```
void empty(float *array, int l);
```

Then put the code in a separate C file, which you compile and link separately.

Comment: "You should never define things in a header". Except when *things* are enums or typedefs.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe No, those are *declarations*. A definition is (typically) something that takes memory in the compiled program. Like the code of a function or the bits of some variable ("object").

Comment: The C11 Standard claims otherwise. See 6.7 (5) Declarations: "A definition [... for an enumeration constant] is the (only) declaration of the identifier" [and similar for typedef name].

Comment: Also, a `typedef` even has "definition" in its name.

Comment: What about "You should never have things in a header that make the compiler emit exported symbols into the object file"?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Feel free to post your own answer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You have the function `empty` defined as a global symbol in the header. This means it will be a visible symbol in all compilation units that include it. There are three general workarounds:

1. make it a static function

   ```
   static void empty(...) {...}
   ```
2. put the implementation into a separate compilation unit

   in `header.h`:

   ```
   void empty(float *array, int l);
   ```

   in `empty.c` implement it
3. instruct your linker to ignore duplicate symbols. This differs from linker to linker, consult `man ld`.

   On OS X: `-m` flag.

   On Linux: `-z muldefs`